# Trouble installing ar_flutter_plugin for augmented reality in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to incorporate augmented reality (AR) into my Flutter app, and I want to display a GLB model on the user's camera feed. I've attempted to use the ar_flutter_plugin to achieve this, but I'm encountering issues with the installation process.

When I built my project on Android I got this error:

> The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
> The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
> project ':ar_flutter_plugin' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

How to install and build that? Is there any other way to use augmented reality in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be building the android project, You need to update gradle plugin version in your android/build.gradle, if you can post your current dependencies that would be helpful..

The following are what the example in your library is using, try ti change your dependencies to the following

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
}
```